# are there any possibility to prevent designers to reach code?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, gitlab

We are using unity to develop games and I set up linux server and running gitlab on the server. I have created the repository for our game. But I want to separate design and code side. I don't want designers to reach code only developers should have access to the codes. at least is it possible to only let designers push and pull between them but not the developer's commits ?

Comment: Use branches in git

Comment: I have 2 branches for developers and designer but from github desktop u can simply switch to master branch and it is protected but still can do

Comment: one way is : create a separate repo for designers, and include this repo as a submodule of the complete repo (accessible to developpers)

Comment: If those designers are your colleagues, then just draw the lines. If they have nothing to do there, then they should not go there. If they are external partners and you are affraid they would access your code, then 1st thing is NDA. Second, if they are designing levels, then you could provide them with an application that runs the interface needed to create levels. Then, the app returns a file you can use in the build. This way, they don't see any code.

Comment: As LeGEC already said use a Submodule (it's an own in itself closed repository). This has its own git history and then the developers can link it into the main project repository as Submodule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Unity 2019 or later, there is also Package Manager option. Basically you can keep all your code in a package project and make that project accessible by only developers. And keep all design assets in a separate project, that depends on your code project. So in that manner designers won't be able to modify somehow your code, and it won't be visible in *Assets* folder.

Comment: yes I am using 2019 and what is it called ? I searched for package manager option but couldnt find

Comment: @user3717626 Under the *Window* tab there is *Package Manager* window. That's where you can import other packages to your project. Just to start, you can publish a package from your code project simply archiving folder containing code you need to publish (for example *Assets/Code*) into a tar archive. Then import that archive to your design project. Otherwise you can setup a sub tree branch in your repo based on subfolder with code, and import that branch. There's a nice article about that: https://medium.com/openupm/how-to-maintain-upm-package-part-1-7b4daf88d4c4